# How do I create something similiar to a "set intersection" that allows for an item to be missing from individual sets n / 1-or-more times?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, set, set-intersection

I want to create a single list of strings that:

**a)** is the interaction of 2 or more lists (the strings that come up in all of the lists), e.x:

```
words = [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "a", "b"], ["f", "a", "g"]]
set.intersection(*(set(t) for t in words))
```

which returns:

```
set(['a'])
```

and

**b)** is the intersection of 2 or more lists, except individual strings may be missing n times from individual sets, or in other words the string can be missing from 1 or more lists, as I deem necessary.

So say I want to allow it to be missing from a single list, applying that logic to the above words variable I should get:

```
set(['a', 'b'])
```

And if I would allow it to be missing from 2 sets it would return all the characters in the above words variable.

I've managed to do **a)**, but how would I got about doing **b)** ?

Comment: looks like you need to have counters...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count how many times each word appears and pick the ones that appear enough:

```
import collections
import itertools
counts = collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(words))

threshold = len(words) - allowed_number_of_times_missing
results = {word for word in counts if counts[word] >= threshold}
```

If words can appear repeatedly in a list, you may want to turn the individual lists into sets so you don't overcount:

```
counts = collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(set(l) for l in words))
```